# SQL: Create case with condition on a field in a temporary table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've a temporary table with 3 fields : an id, a char value with a number (called data) and a char value (called status).

I've to make a check on the status field like that :

```
Declare @sum as int
CASE #temp.status
when #temp.status in (1,2) then
Set @sum = (select SUM(data) FROM #temp groupby id)
When #temp.status in 3 then Set @sum = 1
```

But, i've a incorrect syntax neat the keywork 'Case'. Can you please help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Declare @sum as int

Set @sum = CASE when #temp.status in (1,2) 
                then (select SUM(data) FROM #temp)
                When #temp.status = 3 
                then 1
           END
```

In your subquery you `group by id`. That will most probably return multiple records which you probably don't want.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @sum as int
SELECT @Sum = SUM(CASE WHEN status in (1,2) THEN data WHEN status = 3 THEN 1 END) FROM #temp
```